# Combinatorial Proof of $|T| \leq 2 \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I need some help proving that if $T$ is a collection of subsets of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ such that there doesn't exists $A, B, C \in T$ with $A \subset B \subset C$ then $|T| \leq 2 \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this proof counts as combinatorial.

Let $T_1=\{B\in T\mid \exists A\in T:B\subsetneq A\}$ and show that $T_1$ and $T\setminus T_1$ are anti-chains, which lets us apply [Sperner’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem?wprov=sfti1) to both.

Comment: What do you mean by co-chains here? I understand that if I have to show that something is an anti chain of subsets to use Sperner's Theorem, but not quite following what your proof structure is

Comment: @hoya2021 yes, meant anti-chain. Co-chain is something else. Will edit.